# bq_table_download in R not uploading entire dataset? [images & code included]

Tags: r, dataframe, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a dataset that is 5,219,696 rows. At row 88,052 the data in my cell blanks out. See below. My script is below is the image

[image]

```
options(scipen = 20)
    sql_string = "SELECT * FROM table"
    df_base <- bq_project_query(billing, sql_string)
    df_base <- bq_table_download(df_base, max_results = Inf, page_size = 100000000)
    View(df_base)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the page_size argument. The default value is 10000 and if you increase it too much, errors start to appear. I believe that the parsing of downloaded pages can not complete anymore if the page gets too big.
I found that a value of about 20000 works fine and got rid of any NAs or similar.